# Store file via PHP & AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sendfile

In my js file, I wrote this

```
var data = {
    'atc_file': $('#atc_file')[0].files[0],
};
$.ajax({
    url: strSendUrl,
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(result, request) {
        alert('Success');
    }
});
```

(atc_file is input [type='file'])
But now I don't know how to store the file from PHP, is it possible to send file in this way?

Comment: check on your php function, are you getting file, $_FILES

Comment: If sending a file is possible looks like something you could try out very easily, and what do to with that file in the backend is also well documented. So is there any real problem?

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24939229/4471134)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)